# Create generator from event emitter

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, generator, co

I have a function that does something asynchronously, e.g.,

```
const doSomething = () => {
  request(url)
  .pipe(hasher)
  .on('finish', () => {
    // "return" only here
    return hasher.read();
  });
});
```

I would now like to "wait" in the function until `hasher.read()` can be returned instead of returning early with `undefined` (which is what the above variant does).

Ideally, I'd use `doSomething` as

```
const out = yield doSomething();
```

Any hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/710446)

Answer (score 0):

What about using deferred:

```
const q = require('q');

const doSomething = () => {
  const d = q.defer();

  request(url)
  .pipe(hasher)
  .on('finish', () => {
    // "return" only here
    d.resolve(hasher.read());
  });

  return d.promise;
});
```

Then you can handle it as a promise and use `yield`.